# DNS forwarders not being used when external domain matches AD domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a domain controller set up on Windows Server 2016, the domain name for the AD domain is `example.com`. Every computer connected to this domain is assigned a domain name, which I can see in the `Forward Lookup Zones` of `DNS manager`, for example:

```
DC01.example.com
PC01.example.com
PC02.example.com
```

I also have a few external servers set up which are not connected to the AD domain, but they use the same domain name, for example:

```
webapp.example.com
mail.example.com
```

The issue that I am facing is that the DNS resolver on `DC01.example.com` doesn't seem to be forwarding on requests to the DNS server that I have set up under the `Forwarders` section

For example if I am on `PC01`, which is connected to the domain, and I try to perform an `nslookup` for `webapp.example.com` I get an error. I think this is because `DC01` looks at its `Forward Lookup Zones`, sees that nothing is there for `webapp` and just reports that it cannot be found.

In case it makes any difference, the DC has no Internet access and instead relies on an intermediate DNS server, this is at `10.0.0.2`, I know that this resolver is working correctly because when I use `nslookup webapp.example.com 10.0.0.2` it works without issue.

What configuration is needed to make it so that the domain computers are able to get DNS responses for the external domains?

Comment: for this reason i never use  o tld directly, in cade you had used an sub-domain in my mind you wont consider, howwver this has to be definied in the dns settings to say that its not internal, but in case there are the sane, as work aroubd use cnames

Comment: @djdomi I don't think I would set it up this way if I was to do it again, unfortunately the decision was made years ago and rolling it all back now isn't really an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got what is known as a "split-brain DNS" situation. Because `example.com` is listed as a Forward Lookup Zone, that's the only place your DNS server will look when it is asked to resolve `webapp.example.com`. It will only use the forwarders on the Forwarders tab if it fails to find a zone under Forward Lookup Zones.

So, you'll need to make an A record for `webapp.example.com` in *both* the `example.com` Forward Lookup Zone *and* in whatever DNS system you are using for the general public to be able to resolve your external-facing sites' addresses.

A side benefit of this is that you have the option of using an internal (aka [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)) IP address for `webapp.example.com` in the Forward Lookup Zone entry, and a public address in the public DNS system. That way, your internal users can get to your website at, say, 192.168.100.100, presuming that you have an internal connection from your internal users to your web servers. That keeps the traffic from having to go outside through your firewall only to turn right around (aka "hairpin") and come back in.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to automate this process. It works fine in the example that I gave, but scale it up by 10 and all of a sudden that isn't very feasible. Especially if things are updated in one place but not the other.

Comment: I struggle with that, too. We have a similar setup and we haven't found a better way, so we just remind everyone that it is important to update both locations whenever a change is made. We made some mistakes early, but now it is just part of the process, and we haven't messed up in quite a while. Automation: If your external DNS host has an API, you could write a script that updates your internal DNS and the external DNS (through the API) in a single process. Alternative: don't use the same domain for AD that you do for the public-facing stuff.