# Internal network access to public URLs does not work - slow / sometimes works

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

### Hello.

I have been having trouble with accessing my websites / services from within the internal network that hosts them by using FQDNs aka on VM with IP 10.0.0.5 go to Jira server from the browser using the normal URL "jira.example.com".

I wasn't able to do these requests at all, but recently came across an article that explained how to set this up with iptables. Now, I am trying to get Jira server to work, but it keeps doing weird stuff, cannot load properly and that is because it is trying to access the external URL "jira.example.com" from the internal network e.g. 10.0.0.1.

---

### The setup:

Internal network: **10.0.0.0/24**

External IP: **X.X.X.X/32**

---

#### Gateway: 10.0.0.1/32

- firewall

  - Destination NAT to the corresponding local IPs - **10.0.0.2**
  - Destination NAT when local IPs send requests to the external IP
  - Source NAT when Gateway receives requests from internal network that are meant for the Production server - NAT to **10.0.0.1** (Gateway)
- DNS server

  - Has all domains configured to point to the external IP
- squid cache proxy

  - just caching

Firewall rules (not all obviously):

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d X.X.X.X/32 -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80

-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp -i eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp -d X.X.X.X/32 -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d X.X.X.X/32 -i eth0 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443

-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp -i eth1 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp -d X.X.X.X/32 -i eth0 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443

-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:80
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:80

-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:443
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:443
```

---

#### Production: 10.0.0.2/32

- Nginx web server / proxy

  - reverse proxy for services like Jira so I can access them using public URLs
- Jira server

---

#### The effect

When I access any web using the external URL (from outside - e.g. personal internet connection), I am able to see it and everything works (except Jira - on this subject later). Domains point were they should, the requests are forwarded nicely using firewall, the content is delivered.
I haven't had issues with this.

Now, I needed to have access from the internal network to the external URLs as many apps require setting a "base url", so then you only can access the app using that URL + the app itself uses that URL to do some internal magic stuff.

This is the case with Jira. It uses base url, which is set to the FQDN and it just does not want to load most of the times. It also spits out errors about not being able to access the url from itself.

Initially, I haven't had the SNAT and DNAT for internal network, but now I set it up and it works - partially.

On my Windows 2019 server which runs on the internal network, I can access the different services, but with some problems - Jira is still not responding as it should.

All the servers on the internal network have one and only DNS server set in their network interfaces - which is on the Gateway (10.0.0.1). That means all DNS requests are handled by my own DNS server - it works, I just mentioned it if this was relevant.

On any linux machine (Production, etc.) I run CentOS. When I tried to to curl -v "me.example.com", or "jira.example.com", **these requests did not go through and I would get request timed out, or sometimes, it took around 5 minutes or so to get a response which was actually correct**.

---

Any ideas on what is going mental in my setup? I tried so many things, and did not succeed improving this bizarre issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your setup right, it sounds like you need split DNS. Where requests from inside your network to the local DNS server (10.0.0.1) return results using your private subnet but requests from outside your network to DNS (at your registrar, ISP or a place like DNS Made Easy) returns the public IP.  Otherwise, you're trying to hit the public IP of your site from within your network.

Comment: Yes, it's like you are describing.

For this I found out, I can do DNAT and SNAT so that if the requests come from the private subnet, they are properly dealt with and sent to the corresponding internal VMs.

But maybe this solution is a problem and I will try making custom DNS records for the internal network.

Comment: The key to split DNS is recreating all other DNS records that exist on your external DNS server on your internal DNS other than the ones you are going to "override" and point to internal IPs.  Otherwise, since your internal DNS server has an example.com zone it would return a "host not found" instead of forwarding it to your external DNS.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Here's a discussion related to split DNS although the person incorrectly calls it split brain DNS: https://serverfault.com/q/982266/538169

Comment: I have successfully managed to create separate DNS records for the internal network and it works nice! Only problem is that I will now have to update both DNS zones each time I want to add something. But it's worth it when everything works now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! One way around the bulk double entry is to make multiple host specific local zones. Such as: www.example.com and ftp.example.com instead of just example.com. At least it makes it double entry for only those specific.